# UserControl Data Binding Value lost immediately after setting it

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, user-controls

I have a user control with a view model and some data bindings. I've debugged to see that all the data bindings get set when I change them via the UI. However, whenever I try to read them through a user interaction directly after that, they are null again.

I'm at a complete loss right now. Couldn't find anyone dealing with the same problem so far, or I'm looking in the wrong direction.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

UserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.UserControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Main.ViewModel"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <vm:UserControlViewModel/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DocTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocType, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Content="Load" Command="{Binding SelectFile}" Margin="5"/>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Panel}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UserControlViewModel.vb:

```
Inherits ObservableObject

    Dim _docTypes As List(Of String)
    Dim _selectedDocType As String
    Dim _form As Form
    Dim _selectFile As New RelayCommand(AddressOf OpenFile)

    Public Property Form As Form
        Get
            Return _form
        End Get

        Set(value As Form)
            If value IsNot _form Then
                _form = value
                Me.LoadForm()
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("Form")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Panel As StackPanel
        Get
            Return _panel
        End Get

        Set(value As StackPanel)
            If value IsNot _panel Then
                _panel = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("Panel")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DocTypes As List(Of String)
        Get
            If Me._docTypes Is Nothing Then
                Me._docTypes = DmsConnector.GetDocTypes()
            End If

            Return _docTypes
        End Get

        Set(value As List(Of String))
            Me._docTypes = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged("DocTypes")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SelectedDocType As String
        Get
            Return _selectedDocType
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If value <> _selectedDocType Then
                _selectedDocType = value
                Me.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDocType")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectFile As RelayCommand
        Get
            Return _selectFile
        End Get
    End Property
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    x:Class="View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:avalonDock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="UserControl" DataType="{x:Type vm:UserControlViewModel}">
                        <v:FormControl/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="Sources" DataType="{x:Type vm:SourceViewModel}">
            <v:SourcesControl x:Name="SourcesControl"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Name="PrevButton" Content="{x:Static str:Resources.PreviousStep}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False" Click="PrevButton_Click" />
            <Button Name="NextButton" Content="{x:Static str:Resources.NextStep}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="False" Click="NextButton_Click"/>
        </ToolBar>

        <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="DockingManager">
            <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
                <v:ScanclientAvalonDockTheme />
            </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>

            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="305">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable x:Name="ToolPanelTitleBar" Title="{x:Static str:Resources.Sources}" CanClose="False">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ToolPanel" Content="{Binding}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.DataContext = New SourceViewModel
End Sub

Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Me.PdfIsOpen Then
        If Me.DataContext.GetType = GetType(SourceViewModel) Then

            Me.DataContext = New UserControlViewModel(CType(Me.DataContext, SourceViewModel).Source)
            Me.ToolPanelTitleBar.Title = UserControlViewModel.Title
            Me.PrevButton.IsEnabled = True
        ElseIf Me.DataContext.GetType = GetType(UserControlViewModel) Then
            'something else
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrevButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Me.DataContext.GetType = GetType(UserControlViewModel) Then
        Me.DataContext = New SourceViewModel
        Me.ToolPanelTitleBar.Title = SourceViewModel.Title
        Me.PrevButton.IsEnabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

What I'm doing specifically is changing `SelectedDocType` and setting `Form` and trying to read them after pressing the `Next` button. But they always end up null. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hard for me to read VB code, but I think it's because you create a new UserControlViewModel on each click. And it gets the default values for its properties.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... wouldn't use VB if I didn't had to. But I don't think that's the problem - I set a breakpoint where the view model is set and it only gets called once [when it should be], way before everything is nulled.

Comment: That's not the point, based on your description I understood that you initialize the properties **before** you click 'Next', is it right?

Comment: No. Comment must be at least 15 characters in length.